# populating datetime between two dates without certain datetimes php

Tags: php, datetime

### What I Require

I want to populate datetimes between two datetimes without certain dates which are fetched from database.

### Code

```
    $begin = new Datetime('2013-07-01 11:00');
    $endDate = new Datetime('2013-07-25 15:00');
    $exceptionDates = array('2013-07-05','2013-07-11');

    $interval = DateInterval::createFromDateString('1 day');
    $period = new DatePeriod($begin, $interval, $endDate, DatePeriod::EXCLUDE_START_DATE);
```

How can I exclude the `$exceptionDates` from `$period`?

Comment: Great.  Good luck to you.  Or did you have a question?

Comment: @SeanBright: That was the question. How to exclude the dates?

Comment: By writing the code to exclude the dates.  If your question is "how do I exclude dates from a `DatePeriod` without writing any addition code?" then the answer is: you can't.  You have to write the code yourself.

Comment: @SeanBright: Actually I dont know what to do?

Comment: Iterate over all of the dates between `$begin` and `$endDate` (using a `for` or a `while` loop).  For each date between `$begin` and `$endDate` check to see if that date is in `$exceptionDates`.  If it is, don't do anything with it and move on to the next date.   But don't worry, someone will be along shortly to give you the code for this.

Comment: @SeanBright I feel your pain all too often here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to convert your period to an array beforehand (you have a lot of them for example) you can use a [`FilterIterator`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.filteriterator.php) or a [`CallbackFilterIterator`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.callbackfilteriterator.php) to reject the elements you dont want like this:

```
$begin = new Datetime('2013-07-01 11:00');
$endDate = new Datetime('2013-07-25 15:00');

$interval = DateInterval::createFromDateString('1 day');
$period = new DatePeriod($begin, $interval, $endDate, DatePeriod::EXCLUDE_START_DATE);
$period = new CallbackFilterIterator(new IteratorIterator($period), function ($current, $key, $iterator) {
    return !in_array($current->format('Y-m-d'), array('2013-07-05','2013-07-11'));
});

foreach ($period as $d) {
    var_dump($d->format('Y-m-d'));
}
```

The period is not an iterator in itself so its wrapped with an IteratorIterator. Alternatively you could just convert the period into an array with:

```
$dates = iterator_to_array($period);
```

And use `array_filter()` or `array_diff()` to create the filtered dates array too.

Comment: when I putting $exceptionDates instead of array('2013-07-05','2013-07-11') it gives Message:  Undefined variable: exceptionDates

Comment: This is because unlike functions in javascript or blocks in ruby, anonymous functions in php doesn't automatically get the current scrope they are defined in, you will have to import variables explicitly. You can write it like `function($current, $key, $iterator) use ($exceptionDates) { ... }` [see here](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php).